# Magento Migration Tool: What should the database host, name, user and password be in config.xml?

Tags: magento2-migration-tool

I am hoping to migrate Magento 1.9.4.0 to 2.4.1 using the Magento Migration Tool. I have already installed the Migration tool and now I'm trying to configure the confix.xml file in:

<Magento 2 root dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/<Magento 1.x version>

I already found and inserted the crypt_key, now I suppose to edit the following:

```
<source>
<database host="localhost" name="Magento1-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>
</source>
<destination>
<database host="localhost" name="Magento2-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>
</destination>
```

- **Localhost** --> I've put the IP address of both the source and destination (they are both in the same hosting package but have different IP addresses) - *Is this correct?*
- **name** --> I copied the database name from phpMyAdmin - *Is this correct?*
- **user** --> **what should this be?** *Is this the cPanel user name or the Magento Admin user name?*
- **password** --> *again - cPanel password OR Magento Admin password?*

After I get the correct settings in here, can I just run these 2 commands via SSH (Putty) to make the Migration tool migrate all the important data?

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset <path to your config.xml>

php bin/magento migrate:data --reset <path to your config.xml>
```

**Also, do I need to put the Magento 1 store in maintenance mode prior to doing the migration?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get database credentials:-

> For Magento1.x -> goto ../app/etc/local.xml 
> For Magento2.x -> goto
> ../app/etc/env.php

Copy these credentials to

```
<source>
<database host="localhost" name="Magento1-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>
</source>
<destination>
<database host="localhost" name="Magento2-DB-name" user="DB-username" password="DB-password"/>
</destination>
```